# Changing value of shapekeys keyblocks with a specific name for all objects inside a Blender collection

Tags: python, scripting, shape-keys, collections

This is my code right now:

```
import bpy

for k in bpy.data.shape_keys.keys() :
    bpy.data.shape_keys[k].key_blocks["Opened"].value = 0
```

It change the value of all shapekeys keyblocks with the name "Opened" to 0. I do that because I model a bag and I want 2 versions of it, opened and closed, for rendering. The problem is the I don't want to change the shapekeys in other scenes, and with this current code that's what's happening. I need a way to access shape_keys keyblocks that are only applied to the objects in the collection of my choice. How may I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Get the collection by its name and loop over mesh objects (or others that have shape keys) in it to reach their shape keys.

```
import bpy

collection_name = "Collection"

collection = bpy.data.collections.get( collection_name )

if collection:
    for obj in [o for o in collection.objects if o.type == 'MESH']:
        key_block = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.get( "Opened" )
        if key_block:
            key_block.value = 0
```